# How to undo call-last-kbd-macro in emacs

Tags: emacs, undo

In emacs, I sometimes invoke call-last-kbd-macro by mistake. When undoing I would have expected undo to undo the entire effect of the keyboard macro atomically, but that does not happen. Instead I find myself having to undo each step of the macro one at a time. How can I get emacs to return to the buffer state before the execution of the macro?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you can't do that with just the built-in `'undo` mechanism.  The macro system in Emacs actually plays things back as though the user were actually typing in the keystrokes (or mouse events), and so the [undo history](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Undo1.2.3.-) (`buffer-undo-list`) gets updated as normal.

Here's a suggestion of how to extend the current `undo` mechanism to do what you want.

1. extend `'undo` to understand a new entry in the undo list, a `macro-begin` marker and a `macro-end` element
2. advise/change the macro playback to insert the markers at the beginning/end of the macro playback
3. have the `undo` code treat all undo events between the two markers as a unit and undo them all (and add the appropriate markers on the end of the undo history so when you `redo` things, they're still treated as a single block)

Caveats:

- This would only work for macros that operate in a single buffer, if your macro switched buffers (or had side effects in other buffers), those changes would not be treated as a block.
- If your macro ended in a different buffer than it started, then you'd have to handle that cleanly - you don't want "unbalanced" `macro-begin` and `macro-end` markers in the undo list.

Needless to say, this is a complicated endeavor.  I wish you luck.

Comment: Thanks Trey. Indeed a complex answer. A simpler but more hackish solution in the same spirit would be to make call-last-kbd-macro (or a wrapper) insert some kind of no-op marker in the undo list. And then create a new function clear-to-macro-marker that would undo all changes until the marker was hit.

Comment: Along those lines is http://www.panix.com/~harley/elisp/undo-group.el which adds a marker namely two `nil`s which it then uses as a boundary for an `undo-group` command.

Answer (score 3):

[13 years later...] Simply run the command `(with-undo-amalgamate (call-last-kbd-macro))`.

The [`with-undo-amalgamate`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Undo.html#index-with_002dundo_002damalgamate) command was introduced in Emacs 29.1; it makes this sort of task much easier.

To make prefix arguments and whatnot work, here's what I have in my `.emacs`:

```
(defun undoable-call-last-kbd-macro (&optional PREFIX LOOPFUNC)
  "Thin wrapper around `call-last-kbd-macro' so that the <undo> command undoes the entire macro."
  (interactive "p")
  (with-undo-amalgamate (call-last-kbd-macro PREFIX LOOPFUNC)))
```

This does exactly what you want. (Edge case: say you call it with a prefix command, eg `M-5 call-last-kbd-macro`. Then `<undo>` will undo all 5 applications of the macro, not just the fifth. This makes sense; it's consistent with how "undo" handles other commands with prefix arguments.) The same trick works for making `kmacro-end-or-call-macro` atomically undoable.

---

Sidenote: you can do the same thing with named macros. Eg, if you have the keybinding

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'my-macro)
```

you should replace it with

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") (lambda () (interactive) (with-undo-amalgamate (my-macro))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done pretty easily by overriding `undo-boundary` with e.g. the `noflet` package.

Given a macro definition (as generated by `insert-kbd-macro`) as follows:

```
(fset 'my-macro
   [... keys ...])
```

or:

```
(fset 'my-macro
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([...keys...] 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

Edit it as such:

```
(require 'noflet)

(fset 'my-macro
      (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p")
        (undo-boundary)
        (noflet ((undo-boundary ()))
          (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([...keys...] 0 "%d")) arg))
        (undo-boundary)))
```

If you don't want to edit all your macro definitions, you could alternatively add a wrapper which invokes a macro given as an argument, while creating / suppressing undo boundaries as above.